# Error Logging into Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to run the Official Google Code Sample for Google Play Services with the Type-A-Number code that is on their [github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/TypeANumber). But when I try signing in I get this "4:" error, and the only ids.xml values that I don't know what to replace with are these two: [image]

[image: Error]

Could it be the debug key I'm using? Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ids.xml inside project should be replaced with ids.xml provided from the Google Play Console. You can find this file by clicking the `Get Resources` link in the Events, Achievements, or Leaderboards menu of the Google Play Console.

Comment: I have done this but it does not give me the event IDs, nor does it tell me how to set them up. Even the auto ID generator in the Github instructions does not give me an event ID. What do I do? Everything else I can fill out fine.